# Validate checkboxes with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to validate checkboxes using javascript, and if validation fails - show div with `invalid-feedback` under checkboxes.
Unfortunately when I add `invalid-feedback` class to my div, it disappears.

`````
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1" oninput="validateCheckbox()">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                    checbkox1
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck2" oninput="validateCheckbox()">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck2">
                    Checbkox12
                  </label>
                </div>
            <div id="checkboxIdError">NEED TO HAVE invalid-feedback class</div>
       </div>````
`````

Answer (score 0):

Here is the bootstrap validation http://bootstrapvalidator.votintsev.ru/validators/choice/